# JQuery trigger an function

Tags: php, jquery, timeout

I had [this](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout) jquery idle timeout script implemented into a site, thanks to ehynds for the great job.

Everything is working fine except below part:

```
onTimeout: function(){
    window.location = "timeout.htm";
},
```

There is another function which will handle the logout process in the same page, I want the onTimeout will trigger a logout function when the timer is reached, which is like below:

```
onTimeout: function(){
   // call a logout function here;
},
```

How can I call the function load inside onTimeout block?

Comment: read http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the control whose event you want to trigger.

```
onTimeout: function(){
    $('#foo').trigger('click');
}
```

or You can call function staightway.

```
onTimeout: function(){
    SomeFunction();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin works as it looks like it should - what you pasted is the function you are looking for. If you want to call a seperate function:

```
onTimeout: function(){
    anotherFunction();
},
```

but any code inside there should be called if the plugin is functioning correctly. Test like so:

```
onTimeout: function(){
    alert('i will put my logout function here');
},
```

if you dont get an alert dialog after the timeout period.. i would say its a problem with the plugin.

Comment: the alert dialog can show up, how can I call a function in it??

Comment: `onTimeout: function(){
    anotherFunction();
},`